# SDL and SFML not working with Xcode 5

Tags: xcode

I got used to VS quiet well, but hopped to Mac. OS X is fantastic, and I'm playing with Xcode now. I do not like it... For Apple related stuff it is great, but God, SFML and SDL are not working! I got same problem with both! I installed Command line Tool, and installed both Frameworks and everything, made templates, but when I build my main.cpp, it get's broken in same place. On the line `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` it says can't find Foundation/Foundation.h, and I tried adding path, and fiddling all the things in build phase, but still nothing. It is so frustrating! I can't wait for JetBrains to release their C++ IDE. Can anybody help me with these? I tried recompiling SDL2, since it was crashing Xcode but then I got that Foundation.h is missing. SFML is showing me the same thing, even if I created template and everything else is perfect. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add Foundation.framework to your Xcode project. To do that:

1. Click on your project's icon in the Project Navigator pane. This will show you the various targets in your project. (There's probably only 1 if you've just made the project.)
2. Click on the target you're trying to build, then click the "Build Phases" tab.
3. Twirl open the section named "Link Binary With Libraries" and click the "+" button. It will display a dialog with a list of the standard frameworks. There's a search box at the top. You can just type "Foundation" and it will find it.
4. Select it, and click "Add". That should add it to your target.